# Pod Priority and Preemption

Tags: kubernetes

I was reading about [**Pod Priority and Preemption**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/), I had a question in my mind.

Lets say A is higher priority pod and B is lower one. B is already running , A came along and now it eviction had to be happened. Note that B is of type JOB. I wanted to ask, If B is evicted. will it be rescheduled later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is Yes.

> If a pending Pod has inter-pod affinity to one or more of the lower-priority Pods on the Node, the inter-Pod affinity rule cannot be satisfied in the absence of those lower-priority Pods. In this case, the scheduler does not preempt any Pods on the Node. Instead, it looks for another Node. The scheduler might find a suitable Node or it might not. There is no guarantee that the pending Pod can be scheduled